# Non zero exit status

Tags: r, error-handling

I have been trying to install the baseballr package using the following commands:

`if (!requireNamespace('devtools', quietly = TRUE)){ install.packages('devtools') } devtools::install_github(repo = "BillPetti/baseballr")`

`# install.packages("devtools") devtools::install_github("BillPetti/baseballr", ref = "development_branch")enter code here`

After the code runs, I receive an error message saying that the installation had "non-zero exit status". How could I correct this issue?

Comment: There's probably a more descriptive error message earlier in the output. Please share the entire output of the command so we can see where the error occured.

Comment: Yes. Some information on the error messages you get would be very helpful.

Comment: Attached is the entire output of the command. Part 1 `Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pmosb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'baseballr' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required`

Comment: Part 2 `Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'baseballr'
* removing 'C:/Users/pmosb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/baseballr'
Warning in i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/pmosb/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuAnk9V/filef53473ec44f0/baseballr_1.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> if (!requireNamespace('devtools', quietly = TRUE)){
+   install.packages('devtools')
+ }`